# Can not change a file in docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-swarm

I run a real elasticsearch cluster in a production environment using consul +overlay +docker,I attach a container, When I change elasticsearch.yml,another file which name is elasticsearch.yml~ appears,  then I run elasticsearch ,there has a error 
[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchException[Failed to load logging configuration]; nested: NoSuchFileException[/usr/local/biop/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml~];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/local/biop/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml~
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:99)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:225)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:372)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2706)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.resolveConfig(LogConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

I don't know why there will have this file which name is 'elasticsearch.yml~'and it can't be deleted. How to solve this problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The extra file is created by your text/code editor. Once you are done editing your text file, you should simply delete it.

It seems that docker try to use it as a configuration file.

However, it might be that the error "[Failed to load logging configuration]" is not caused by that itself, there is probably not so good configuration about logging in your elastisearch.yml anyway.

Comment: If the error persist once you have edited your file then removed the elastistearch.yml~, could you post your configuration about logging ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/settings.html
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

Comment: I changed all configuration files ,then all of them would appear ~ files which can't be deleted.

Comment: Once the docker machines are shut down, could you try to remove these files with sudo rm elasticsearch.yml~ ?